# magento How to add a block to the bundled product page

Tags: magento

I am a newcomer to magento. During the learning process, I want to know how to add a block to the bundled product page. The piece of information I found through google doesn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you want to put it, and I am assuming that you have a theme setup with a `local.xml` file, but you could also add that part in the product's edit page in `Admin->Manage Products->Edit Product->Design->Custom Layout Update`.

The xml, added in `app/design/frontend/[your-theme]/[your-subtheme]/layout/local.xml`

```
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
        <reference name="content">
            <block name="yourtheme_yoursubtheme_nameofblock" type="core/text" template="path/to/your/template.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
```

This will add the output of `app/design/frontend/[your-theme]/[your-subtheme]/template/path/to/your/template.phtml` at the bottom of every **bundle-type** product page.  You may want to read up on [Magento Layout XML](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/)